# in visual studio 2013 default page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, default

In visual studio 2013 default.aspx page is not firing

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("hello");
    }
```

Please help me for solving this.

In page directives _default is apperence and other page same name is display like if my page is register so inheritance from register

Comment: This looks pretty valid code so I'm not sure how you expect us to be able to help? What is the *exact* issue?

Comment: Page is run but page_load not fire

Comment: what is `page_load`, an event when the page is loaded or a custom event? Is this asp.net?

Comment: When we add page page_load is comes with their

Comment: In page directives _default is apperence and other page same name is display like if my page is register so inheritance from register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're lacking details here, but is there any reason you're not overloading `OnLoad`? 
http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/onload-vs-page-load-vs-load-event